# adding gui to interface

Tags: c#, interface

I'm using 'interface' class to connect my main application with my dll library. The problem is that I want my library to have it's own configuration form, which will be called from the main application. I'm not sure where to start. How can I add a form to my dll library and then be able to call it from main application?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Add one function to your interface that creates the form. Just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Include the UI dll (WPF or WinForms whatever) to project dependencies of your dll project.
2. Create a form within your dll library as usual like you do in main app.
3. In main app create an instance of this form and call .Show() (or ShowDialog() for modal)

That is, you will see the form from your dll.